# Работа со split

Tags: c#

Есть строка:

```
11-11111
```

Нужно разбить её в 2 текстбокса, в первый до тире, во второй после. Тире не куда не нужно.
Как разбить до тире я вроде бы понял.

```
txbPartySelect.Text = part_id.Split(new Char[] {'-'}).ToString();
```

Если не ошибаюсь это работает.
И нужно ещё во второй записать всё что идёт после тире. Как это сделать?

Comment: Split возвращает массив строк  https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx, если с массивами работать умеете, то и получить разные части строки сможете

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как уже ранее отметили в комментарии Split возвращает строковый массив, так что того, чтобы получить второй элемент, вам надо указать его индекс string.Split(separator)[index]:

```
 string[] parts = part_id.Split(new Char[] {'-'});
 txbPartySelect.Text = parts[0]; //Получаем первый элемент
 youSecondTextBox.Text = parts[1]; //получаем второй элемент
```

Comment: зачем два раза мучить метод Split и ToString?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский согласен, сейчас исправлю, спасибо за замечание

Answer (score 5):

```
string str = "11-11111";
string[] spl = str.Split('-');

txb1.Text = spl[0];
txb2.Text = spl[1];
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fnZMje)